# What is the SMMA flag?

Tags: memory, computer-architecture

I'm new to computer architecture.  What is the full form of the SMMA flag?  Where is it used?  Please help me understand it with a brief description.

Comment: for reference: http://books.google.com/books?id=YT74AkSrj4sC&pg=PA199&lpg=PA199&dq=%22smma+flag%22&source=bl&ots=4qqytCMTYb&sig=lk3XbL4R2HElv6xbGaXpLSFAnEc&hl=en&ei=KJOgS5L1Go6QtgfC4tnyBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22smma%20flag%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

> The SMMA flag indicates whether a
>   memory operation is already in
>   progress. If it is 0, no memory
>   operation is in progress. If it is 1,
>   a memory operation is in progress.
>   When the processor changes the state
>   of SMMA from 0 to 1, the memory starts
>   the operation. On completion of the
>   operation, the memory control logic
>   resets the flag. Obviously, this will
>   be done after the memory access time
>   is over. The MFC signal from memory
>   can be used to reset this flag.

[Source](http://books.google.com.tr/books?id=YT74AkSrj4sC&pg=PA199&lpg=PA199&dq=SMMA+flag%3F&source=bl&ots=4qqytCNNX9&sig=2OSNA73HkPwWpFmyumU2AKU0Pas&hl=tr&ei=rJSgS_DuC5yPsAaV1_C-DQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CAgQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=SMMA%20flag%3F&f=false)

Comment: seriously?  a screenshot of the explanation?  from the link i posted? not helpful.  you could at least take the time to type in the quote, so the text is searchable or cut-n-paste-able.

Comment: I made a web search and found it, I did NOT take it from your post! If taking a screenshot and pasting it in an answer is a guilt, OK, then I'm guilty. Besides, I give the source at the bottom of my message.

Comment: ok, finding the link on your own is certainly fair.  (it's the same page i linked to in the comment above; link is too complicated for me to eyeball as identical or not.)  still, screenshots of text are not good.  i'll take off the downvote when it's actual text.